# Xamarin iOS/UWP using DocumentDB

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a simple app with PCL that works with Android, but on iOS and UWP I get problems related to Azure Cosmos DocumentDB (SQL Api).

I am working from a Windows 10 PC, building with VS2017 15.5.6, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 11.6.14.  I am connected to a Mac Mini.

My app connects to Azure Cosmos DocumentDB.  Android builds, deploys, runs, and I can/have put it in Play Store, downloaded, and it runs just great. I can connect my android phone locally and deploy/debug on it just great.

On UWP, it builds fine and I can debug locally on my desktop, but when I tried to submit the app to the Windows Store, I got a certification error saying:

```
Error Found: The binary analyzer test detected the following errors:
File DocumentDB.Spatial.Sql.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
File Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
```

On iOS I don't even get that far.  When I try to build and deploy to the simulator running on the Mac Mini, I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(777,3): error : Error while loading assemblies: /Users/marksn/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Evaluator.iOS/9a9b6b5e46314f88260c821e5b69ea96/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/DocumentDB.Spatial.Sql.dll
```

I have updated all my Nuget packages.  I have deleted my bin and obj folders.  I tried both debug and release.

I'm under some pressure to get this working and this totally blocks me from moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the bug has been fixed that was blocking submission to the Windows store when the DocumentDB DLL's were referenced.  Once I was prompted on another thread to try again it succeeded without modification to my project.  After downloading and installing the new submission, it worked like a charm just like it had locally within the debugger.